# Display XML tree structure with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, tree

When working with a new XML structure, it is always helpful to see the big picture first.

When loading it with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests, bs4
s = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml').text
x = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
print(x)
```

**is there a built-in way to display its tree structure with different depths?**

---

Example for https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml, with `maxdepth=0`, it would be:

```
CATALOG
```

with `maxdepth=1`, it would be:

```
CATALOG
  CD 
  CD
  CD
  ...
```

and with `maxdepth=2`, it would be:

```
CATALOG
  CD 
    TITLE
    ARTIST
    COUNTRY
    COMPANY
    PRICE
    YEAR
  CD 
    TITLE
    ARTIST
    COUNTRY
    COMPANY
    PRICE
    YEAR
  ...
```

Comment: Not quite what you're after, but I have used `xmltodict` to parse xml as an ordered dictionary, which can be viewed recursively to a desired depth.

Comment: Could you show an example of code with `xmltodict` @Aramakus? PS: there are multiple versions of `xmltodict` libraries, which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it: Use the `prettify()` function to structure it, then get the indentation and opening tag names via regex (catches uppercase words inside opening tags in this case). If the indentation from `pretify()` meets the depth specification, then print it with the specified indentation size.

```
import requests, bs4
import re

maxdepth = 1
indent_size = 2
s = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml').text
x = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml').prettify()

for line in x.split("\n"):
    match = re.match("(\s*)<([A-Z]+)>", line)
    if match and len(match.group(1)) <= maxdepth:
        print(indent_size*match.group(1) + match.group(2))
```

Comment: Nice solution! Maybe we should have something more  than `<([A-Z]+)>` to also match lowercase, etc. `<opf:metadata>` tags (in EPUB books)

Answer (score 1):

I have used `xmltodict` 0.12.0 (installed via anaconda), which did the job for xml parsing, not for depth-wise viewing though. Works much like any other dictionary. From here a recursion with depth counting should be a way to go.

```
import requests, xmltodict, json

s = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml').text
x = xmltodict.parse(s, process_namespaces=True)

for key in x:
    print(json.dumps(x[key], indent=4, default=str))
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is something like `OrderedDict([('CD', [OrderedDict([('TITLE', 'Empire Burlesque'), ('ARTIST', 'Bob Dylan'), ('COUNTRY', 'USA'), ('COMPANY', 'Columbia'), ('PRICE', '10.90'), ('YEAR', '1985')]), OrderedDict([('TITLE', 'Hide your heart'), ('ARTIST', 'Bonnie Tyler'), ('COUNTRY', 'U...`, how would you produce a human-readable tree structure?

Comment: I think the easiest way is `print(json.dumps(x[key], indent=4, default=str))` , you'll need to add `import json` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution without `BeautifulSoup`.

```
import requests
s = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml').text
array = []

tab_size = 2
target_depth = 2

for element in s.split('\n'):
    depth = (len(element) - len(element.lstrip())) / tab_size
    if depth <= target_depth:
        print(' ' * int(depth) + element)
```